# remove specific character from a string with batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, wildcard

i want to remove only a specific character into a string and only one time. for example, if I have this file:

```
"1234 + test.txt"
```

i want to remove "+" character. my problem is that I don't know how many "+" could be in filename; by the way, I want to remove only the first:

```
"1234 ++ test + hello + world.txt"
```

need to be:

```
"1234 + test + hello + world.txt"
```

I need to do this with a bat script. I have some problems to use correctly "token,delims" parameters....

edit: I've a problem with Edoro's solution. if filename is "++plus--.txt", %left% is "plus--.txt" and %right% is +plus--.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### pure batch

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "string=1234 ++ test + hello + world.txt"

for /f "delims=+" %%i in ("%string%") do set "left=%%i"
set "right=%string:*+=%"
set "new=%left%%right%"
echo %new%
```

..output is:

```
1234 + test + hello + world.txt
```

Comment: if I want to trim also "-", can I use something like "delims=+ -" or I need to use inverted commas?

Comment: In the `for` loop you can use more than one delimiter, but not in string manipulation `set "right=%string:*+=%"`.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't use the same code for absolute different Regex. In this case the `new` string calculation is `set "new=%string:++=+%"`. This is for all similar cases.

Comment: it doesn't seem the solution,because if filename is "+test.txt" the final result will be "test.txt"

Comment: if you have `+test.txt` and use `set "new=%string:++=+%"` you get `+test.txt`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Go through a sed script:

```
echo "1234 + test + hello + world.txt" | sed 's/+//'
```